# Set IMG.width to resize to container (DIV, etc.) width without .js

Tags: html, image, html-email

Is there a way to have an IMG resize it's width (and height to maintain aspect ratio) relative to the containing DIV?

**Use Case**
This is for an email newsletter, so I **can't use .js**  There is a containing div that resizes based on the page width. I want the IMG in it to "obey" that.

I've tried just setting Style="Width:100%" but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Setting the `height` to `auto` is only necessary if a width and height attribute were set in the image tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/e2003kac/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
style="max-width:100%;width:100%;"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use inline-styles:

```
<img style="width: 100%; height: auto;" src="..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it as an attribute, width="100%" ? That should make it work across the board. Height should auto-adjust.